# GraphQL List or single object

Tags: javascript, graphql

I got the following "problem". I am used to having an API like that.

```
/users
/users/{id}
```

The first one returns a list of users. The second just a single object. I would like the same with GraphQL but seem to fail. I got the following Schema

```
var schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
      users: {
        type: new GraphQLList(userType),
        args: {
          id: {type: GraphQLString}
        },
        resolve: function (_, args) {
          if (args.id) {
            return UserService.findOne(args.id).then(user => [user]);
          } else {
            return UserService.find()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
});
```

How can I modify the type of users to either return a List OR a single object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You shouldn't use the same field for different purposes.
Make two fields instead: One for a single object, and another for a list of objects.

It's better practice and better for testing

```
fields: {
    user: {
        type: userType,
        description: 'Returns a single user',
        args: {
            id: {type: GraphQLString}
        },
        resolve: function (_, args) {
            return UserService.findOne(args.id);
        }
    },
    users: {
        type: new GraphQLList(userType),
        description: 'Returns a list of users',
        resolve: function () {
            return UserService.find()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, Just small correction, then then(user => [user]) is not needed anymore :)

Comment: I had the same solution...but under the same name `users` ain't possible?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your schema and everything works correctly. Try console.log on your `[user]` result and see what you get

Comment: Can you tell me why this is better practice? What if you want people to be able to filter the data in several different ways (e.g. min/max age, min/max height, eye colour) - are you creating new fields for each of these, or just adding arguments to the `users` field? If you're adding arguments to the `users` field for those filters, would you still create a separate field for returning 1 user? Or in this case would you simply add `id` as another argument on `users`?

Answer (score -1):

The above answer is correct, the usual approach is to add singular and plural form of queries. However, in large schema, this can duplicate a lot of logic and can be abstracted a little bit for example with Node interface and node, nodes queries. But the nodes query is usually applied with ids as argument (in Relay viz [node Fields](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/master/src/node/node.js)), but you can build your own abstracted way for fetching so that you have just nodes with some argument for type and based on that you can say what type of list to fetch. However, the simpler approach is to just duplicate the logic for every type and use singular and plural form of query and do the same type of queries as above or in this [code snippet](https://github.com/atherosai/express-graphql-demo/blob/feature/5-modifiers/server/graphql/users/userQueries.js) for every type. For more detail explanation on implementing GraphQL list modifiers in queries or even as an input for mutations. I just published the [article](https://graphqlmastery.com/blog/graphql-list-how-to-use-arrays-in-graphql-schema) on that.

Comment: the both uses same endpoint the only differnce is we are passing an  id, if not we need to list the items