# Should GraphQL offer a single item query in addition to the list query?

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

In our application we offer list queries with sorting and filtering and now we were discussing if we should also offer single item queries with the id as parameter.

I've googled a bit and found that very often both queries, list and single item, are implemented.

I'm just wondering why. Wouldn't/Shouldn't a single item query with id as parameter be the same as a list query filtered for id? In both cases the UI should be able to select all properties throughout the graph, right?

Why would the backend care to offer a single item query when the list is already sufficient?

Looking for best practices here.

Comment: what if your list is very large, say 100 million records? would you render the whole thing on the frontend and also, you have to consider the power of the client side machine, if they open it up on a IE in a Pentium 3.... would it even work / give a good experience?

Comment: for usage simplicity, one arg instead of complex condition, easier access w/o array element (existence, not null) checking, etc. ... if often implemented then there is a reason :p

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar usually there is a default pagination (~10 or so) so that's not an issue or why it should be?

Comment: maybe this one is related here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609979/graphql-list-or-single-object

Comment: This depends on your persistence and/or your business layer and what you are doing with your data. Filtering in your business layer is, in most cases, very ressource consuming.